# rails I18n fails to find proper translation file on validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm in the process of upgrading a 3.0.20 app to 4.x. This was done by starting with a blank rails4 directory and adding code/tests.
Things are going well thanks to lots of rspec tests.

When some of the test fail due to validation errors (which are expected), I am getting complaints from I18n, which appears to be trying to load a directory as a translation file.

```
I18n::UnknownFileType: can not load translations from $MYLONGPATH/beaumont4/lib, the file type  is not known
        from (irb):10:in `load_file'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57:in `init_translations'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:40:in `available_locales'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:43:in `available_locales'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:49:in `available_locales_set'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:278:in `locale_available?'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:151:in `translate'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/naming.rb:188:in `human'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:437:in `generate_message'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:449:in `normalize_message'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:300:in `add'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/length.rb:57:in `block in validate_each'
... 40 levels...
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /net/galaxy/home/mcr1002/nv/clientportaltest/beaumont4/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/mcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0):

I determined finally that the problem was that my I18path was borked by me.
I did:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib').to_s]
```

The I18n.loadpath does not take directories, but files.
I meant to do:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib').to_s]
```

ID10T error.